# Group Values in JSONata

Tags: jsonata

Is there a possibility to group items by a specific attribute via JSONata

For example grouping following json by the values form the resultDate.

```json
"Export": [
  {
    "code": "18724-100",
    "resultDate": "11.03.2018 13:11:48"
  },
  {
    "code": "18724-5",
    "resultDate": "11.03.2018 13:11:48"
  },
  {
    "code": "18724-99",
    "resultDate": "14.03.2018 14:11:48"
  }
]
```

To generate the following output:

```json
"Export": [
  {
    "resultDate": "11.03.2018 13:11:48",
    "codes": [
      {
        "code": "18724-100"
      },
      {
        "code": "18724-5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "resultDate": "14.03.2018 13:11:48",
    "codes": [
      {
        "code": "18724-99"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Maybe with a reduce function that groups the elements similar as described in this blog post. https://www.datchley.name/getting-functional-with-javascript-part-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following expression can be used for this:

```
{
  "Export": Export{resultDate: code[]} ~> $each(function($v, $k) {
    {
      "resultDate": $k,
      "codes": $v.{"code": $}
    }
  })
}
```

The first part `Export{resultDate: code[]}` groups the data by `resultDate` then the `$each` function iterates over the name/value pairs to produce the output.  Expressions like this will probably be easier once the `$distinct` function is added to the language (https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/117)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I need to group some objects by a common property (like `resultDate`), I create a single object using that property's value as the key, and removing that property from each of the original objects. Then I use the `$spread()` function to split that big object into an array of objects, each with a single property. The last step is to replace the first (and only) key of each object with the original property name.

The JSONata expression to do this is a bit convoluted:

```
{
    "Export": $spread(Export {
        resultDate: [
            $ ~> | $ | {}, "resultDate" |
        ]
    }).{
        "resultDate": $keys()[0],
        "codes": *
    }
}
```

You can try it for yourself by going to [this exerciser link](http://try.jsonata.org/ryz2qVVem).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way of grouping in general is:

1. create the resulting structure with the key to group by
2. take the array of values thereafter

PS. I like *Andrew Coleman* answer better though

So for this question, that would go like:

```
${
    resultDate: {
        "resultDate": $distinct(resultDate),
        "codes": code.{"code": $}
    }
} ~> $each(function($v){$v})
```